# Attempting to vote on a comment revealed that an answer was a low quality queue audit

Tags: bug, review-audits

[Audit Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5271749) (answer only visible to 10k users)

My reaction here was to up vote Kidd's comment on the off chance it wasn't a troll, and then hit the recommend deletion button.  The error message I got gave away that it was an audit.  In the normal case I'd suggest that a comment up vote should count as a pass for the audit.

[image]

Comment: No, a *comment* upvote should not count as anything. Comment upvotes indicate agreement with the comment; they don't have anything whatsoever to do with the quality of the question or answer.

Answer (score 4):

Can't really complain too much here; if you'd made it that far and then clicked "Looks OK", then we'd have a problem.